# symlink issue when run the php artisan storage:link in cpanel server

Tags: php, symlink, undefined-function

when running the PHP artisan storage:link
shows this error

Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\symlink()
it is working on my local pc when I deployed and run the command then show the error.
I have tried to fix this issue not been resolved yet
Does anybody help me, please?

here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time `symlink` is disabled due to security issues.

If it is hosted on your own server, enable the symlink function. If it is hosted on a shared host, please contact your hosting provider to enable it for you.